# Stable element ordering issue while iterating HashMap in Java 8

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, linkedhashmap

Some test cases are failing in my application which depends upon the element insertion order . It used to work fine in Java 7 but this issue started after upgrading to Java 8. While searching internet I found this in an  [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes8.html):

> Java 8 includes some possible changes to HashSet/Map iteration order:

Can some please suggest me - how can I iterate the objects in a Map in the same order as the insertion order into the Map, considering I would still be using Java 1.8 in my dev environment?

Yes of course it was never assured by HashMap that the objects can be retrieved in the same order , but yes it used to work in java 7.

Does `LinkedHashMap` work to implement this ?

Comment: What does the `LinkedHashMap` documentation tell you?

Comment: Have you checked what Java 7 `HashMap` documentation says ?: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html : **This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.**  You must use other collection that guarantes the order - LinkedHashMap

Comment: Use a `TreeMap` instead from the javaDocs: A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - it tells that , it will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map . I think `LinkedHahMap` will solve this problem - but still wanted to confirm it if anyone has already faced this issue and fixed it.

Comment: The proper way to confirm it is to *try* it. It's a lot less efficient to ask humans if this will work than to simply try it in your exact situation on the machine.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you must use `LinkedHashMap` which has a stable iteration order even across Java versions, as enforced by its [contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map.

On several occasions, we also needed repeatable iteration order across different Java versions and `LinkedHashMap` worked just fine.

---

`TreeMap` would also be a solution for stable iteration order. Of course, it has a logarithmic operation time (as opposed to constant in `LinkedHashMap`) and the iteration order is not insertion order but key order:

> The map is ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator typically provided at sorted map creation time.